# Flask SQLAlchemy inserts null value for text field in PostgreSQL despite text

Tags: postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

The commands in the `books()` method are based on code that already works. The `INSERT INTO` statement is the problem.  When the HTML form is submitted (bottom of screen) the `userreview` in the input field text box is not pulled by my `books()` method and inserted into my postgres DB, despite the presence of text. To check whether or not anything from the HTML page was being pulled in properly, I tested the hidden `book_id`, and it was pulled by the `books()` method and inserted, as expected, into the DB.

Any idea why this would steadfastly refuse to pull text from an input field into my method and insert it into my DB?

```
@app.route("/books", methods=["POST"])
@login_required
def books():
    book_id = request.form.get("bookid")
    review = request.form.get("userreview")
    db.execute("INSERT INTO test (review, bookid) VALUES (:review, :bookid)", {"review": review, "bookid":book_id})
    db.commit()

{% block body %}

<div>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><strong>Username</strong></th>
                <th><strong>Review</strong></th>
                <th class="text-center"><strong>Rating</strong></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        {% for review in reviews %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ review.username }}</td>
            <td>{{ review.reviews }}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{ review.rating }}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
</div>

<form action="{{ url_for('books') }}", method="post">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input name="userreview" type="text" class="form-control" id="bookreview">
    <input type="hidden" name="bookid" value="{{ books.id }}" />
  </div>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This HTML works just fine, though I have yet to figure out what part of the markup made the difference. I thought it was the errant comma in the above code `<form action="{{ url_for('books') }}", method="post">`, but that makes no difference.

```
<form action="{{ url_for('books') }}" method="post">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form control" name="userreview" type="text"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input autocomplete="off" autofocus class="form control" name="bookid" value="{{ books.id }}" type="hidden"/>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```